# dijit.tree how to implement a collapse all functionality using only store?

Tags: javascript, treeview, dojo, dijit.tree

I have a lazy loading dijit.tree which I want to reuse in many places after its data has been loaded. But if I just replace the store object in the other trees with the one which contains most data, the nodes come all expanded. I want to modify the store so that all the items are collapsed before setting it as a store in the new tree. can you tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the store for this, as it does not contain any information of the state of the tree nodes. This 'magic' is performed via `TreeNode`, see some [examples here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Tree-examples.html#expanding-and-focusing-tree-nodes-programmatically)

The 'perfect solution' would be to figure out which paths you need expanded and then set the path of your tree to traverse into the wanted treenodes.

However, since your lazyloading, you need to check the `state` - while initializing a tree it should be `UNCHECKED`. However there is a cookie-functionality inbuilt which probably is kicking in, make sure to create new tree's with `{ persist:false }`

You could also extend your tree, so that it will accept `collapseChildren(TreeNode)` as follows - and then call `tree.set("path", [pathsArray]);`

```
collapseChildren : function(top) {
        var self = this;
        if(!top || !self.model.mayHaveChildren(top.item)) return;
        top.getChildren().forEach(function(n) {
                if(n.item.children) {
                        //dojo.style(n.getParent().containerNode, { overflowY: 'hidden', overflowX: 'hidden'});
                        self._collapseNode(n);
                        self.collapseChildren(n);
                }
        });
},
```

EDIT:

> If the autoExpand flag is passed to the constructor, the Tree is initially shown with all nodes expanded.
>
> You can then call collapseAll() and expandAll() to collapse and expand the Tree, respectively.
> http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/Tree-examples#id3

Comment: look the issue is that when I set only the store of the old tree as the store of the new tree, I see the nodes expanded exactly as they were in the previous tree. So I think it IS based on the store.

Comment: tried using persist:false as stated above? The clicks on a tree generates a cookie for storing tree paths inbetween page-loads, thinking it might be same thing here? Does your newly created tree's fire XHR on the 'opening' child containers?

Comment: make sure the autoExpand flag is false, then use `tree.set("path", [pathsArray]);` to open those which u want opened